# Get the name of the shell script from inside a function

Tags: shell-script, ksh, function

Say I've got this:

```
#!/bin/sh
function show_help {
  cat<<%
Usage: $0 [-h]
%
}
# the following lines is pseudo-code
if argument contains "-h"
  show_help
otherwise
  do_stuff
```

If I run `./test` it does some stuff as intended, but if I run `./test -h`, it produces

```
Usage: show_help [-h]
```

but I intended to let it produce

```
Usage: ./test [-h]
```

so how can I achieve this by modifying only the `show_help` function? I don't want to modify the script itself, so I won't just add `SCRIPT_NAME=$0` under the shebang line.
I hope the solution is some kind of a builtin variable like `$PWD` or function like `pwd`, does there really exist one?

Comment: Since you prevent us from giving you a good solution, what is the point of asking the question?  You already know the best way to do it.  Any other solution will be ugly as hell.

Comment: Your only other option AFAIK is to pass $0 to `show_help`.

Comment: @PM2Ring:  That's an interesting alternative indeed.  If you post that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: How on earth can [using `ksh` cause the problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343064/get-the-name-of-the-shell-script-from-inside-a-function/343069#comment607119_343086) when [`/bin/sh` is linked to `dash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343064/get-the-name-of-the-shell-script-from-inside-a-function/343069#comment607085_343072) and the question is tagged [tag:bash]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this. The question is tagged with '/bash'.

With bash, $0 is always the name of the script, so if this is in /tmp/test

```
#!/bin/bash
function show_help {
cat <<%
Usage: $0 [-h]
%
}
show_help
```

then `bash /tmp/test` gives me `Usage: /tmp/test [-h]`.

If I use `ksh93 /tmp/test` I do get `Usage: show_help [-h]`, due to the ksh setting $0 when you declare a function in a non POSIX manner.

Switching to a portable function declaration

```
#!/bin/bash
show_help() {
cat <<%
Usage: $0 [-h]
%
}
show_help
```

and you get `Usage: /tmp/test [-h]` from both ksh and bash.

So there are multiple errors in the original script. The `#!/bin/sh` should be `#!/bin/bash` if the question is about bash, the function declaration is incorrect, and the syntax of the `if` at the end is just wrong.

Comment: That's it. I found that it's Korn Shell's special handling that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

In BASH, use $FUNCNAME[1].  $FUNCNAME[0] is the show_help.  You an also get the line number in the parent function that called show_help as well as the name of the source file  ($BASH_LINENO[1], $BASH_SOURCE[1]).

I am looking for a similar answer for korn shell (ksh)

Answer (score -1):

Since this question seems to be homework question. So I am not answering in a exact way but putting some hints down.

1. Get the parent PID of running process from `grep PPid /proc/self/status | awk '{print $2}`
2. Find out it's executable name `ls /proc/<PPid>/exe`
3. Use readlink to print out the name of above softlink `readlink /proc/<PPid>/exe`

Output of **3** is the name of running script.

Comment: It's not working. That link is actually poiting to `/bin/dash` which is also the target of `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Not all systems supporting `bash` have `/proc` and all Bourne-style shells including `bash` (and at least `tcsh` also) have a special variable `$$` giving the shell's pid. But as noted, the executable for the shell process `/proc/$$/exe` is the shell not the script; the script (if any) will be open on _some_ fd but IME not always the same one.